# Extract list of Strings in R

Tags: r, stringr

I am very new to R and am facing the following issue with extracting strings from a column of a dataframe

Lets say I have a column A from dataframe Test with the following data in it. I would like to create another column B which would extract "John", "Mary" and "Peter" for each of the rows.

```
asdsad John asdasd
asdasd John asdasd
asdsad Mary 23123
aasdadsadsad Peter 123124
lkxfhsadf John aspowe1 123poi 
asmansd Mary p12 SL asp1
asldk John 123[p asda 214!@$
```

Currently I am using the following code to extract the information but it is not working

```
library(stringr)

list <- c("John", "Peter", "Mary")
Test$B <- str_extract(Test$A, list)
```

I get the following output when I run the code.

```
                             A     B
                           <chr> <chr>
1            asdsad John asdasd  John
2            asdasd John asdasd  <NA>
3             asdsad Mary 23123  Mary
4     aasdadsadsad Peter 123124  <NA>
5 lkxfhsadf John aspowe1 123poi  <NA>
6      asmansd Mary p12 SL asp1  Mary
7  asldk John 123[p asda 214!@$  John
```

Can anyone help me out on why I am getting N/A in some of them? What is happening here and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you not get a warning message when you ran that code? The `pattern=` argument of `str_extract` does not separately match each pattern (what would it return if there were more than one name in a given string?). Instead it uses vector recycling to test a different pattern against each input.

Comment: Yes I get the following error message:
Warning message:
In stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: `Test$B <- str_extract(Test$A, paste(c("John", "Peter", "Mary"), collapse = "|"))`

Comment: Thank you for the comment and link. Super helpful